# Confuse about react redux reducer state design

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

For example, I have a reducer to manipulate user state, like creating user, editing, fetching user.

should I create state for each action, like:

```
{
  loadingForFetching: false,
  fetchingResult: null,
  fetchingError: '',

  loadingForEditing: false,
  editingResult: null,
  editingError:'',

  loadingForCreating: false,
  creatingResult: null,
  creatingError: ''
}
```

Or let the three action share the same state:

```
{
   loading: false,
   result: null,
   error: ''
}
```

I think the share one is a bad idea, because when fetch and create a user at the same time, if one action is complete, by setting loading to `false`, it may mislead another action is complete too. However, the use case is rare, maybe I worry too much

Am I right?

Comment: What does the "result" field contain besides null?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen It could be the fetching result; or creating request response

Comment: Is the "fetching result" different from the user entity itself?

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen no

Comment: In that case I think your `fetchingResult` should rather be called `users` and be an array.

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen yes you are right, thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0):

I don't think data like "loading" or "error" belongs in a global data store and should rather be kept as local component state. It's not persistent, and shouldn't be needed by other components. The only thing out of these I might put in a global data store would be a user entity itself, because that might be accessed by other components.

Comment: I do agree with you. But each redux tutorials I read seems put all these three things together in reducer state. Is there some other  tutorials implement the way you described ?

Comment: @hh54188 I don't know about any good tutorials, but I think with a little thought it's easy to decide what state needs to be shared between everything and what doesn't.

Comment: I disagree. React components are all about display, not data management. That's the whole point of Redux - to keep them separate. Components are for display, data goes in the store, and container components map data from the store to the format your view components need. If you keep your state data in a component, you don't need Redux.

Answer (score 0):

It is data-structure-wised. 
So far I use

```
{
  targetState: {
    data: [{id: 1...}, {id: 2} ... ],
    loading: false,
    loaded: false,
    error: null,
    ... // you could put more information if you like, such activeTarget etc
  }
}
```

if there is more nested data there, need to consider normalizing state shape.
https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to keep loading status in your state, then you better use counter pattern, but not true/false flag.

```
const loadingReducer = (state = 0, action) => {
    if (action.type === 'LOADING_FOR_EDITING' ||
        action.type === 'LOADING_FOR_CREATING' ||
        ...) {
        return state + 1;
    }
    if (action.type === 'LOADING_FOR_EDITING_SUCCESS' ||
        action.type === 'LOADING_FOR_CREATING_SUCCESS' ||
        ...) {
        return state - 1;
    }
    return state;
};

// root reducer:
export default combineReducers({
     loading: loadingReducer,
     loadedData: loadedDataReducer,
     // ...etc
});
```

Now in your components you are able to check loading status, for example like this `const isLoaded = state.loading === 0;`

This approach allows you to control multiple async requests.